# GCD sendSynchronousRequest applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Every time my app loads it calls a web service to check if an update is available to download for the app. If there is it downloads it.

I'm using Grand Central Dispatch to synchronously download the updates in a different thread so I can show a loading icon on my main thread. I need to synchronously download because the app needs the updates before it continues.

However the problem occurs if the download takes a while and the screen goes to sleep, effectively calling applicationDidEnterBackground. When the user turns the screen back on and the app resumes I get the following error:

```
EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

What is the best way around this? Trying to pause the download and resume again when the app resumes or to create a background task and continue downloading? I'm not sure which is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest answer would be that, unless your app otherwise has background privileges (audio, gps, external device, etc), yes, you should pause/stop any network downloads when `-applicationDidEnterBackground` is called and resume when your app comes back.